# geom_point issue when plotting datetime data

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
metric type time_stamp
1.879425 blah 2015-10-29 18:39:19 
1.239894 bluh 2015-10-29 20:39:19
```

`s = ggplot(aes(y="metric",x="time_stamp",color='type'),data = tmp_df) + geom_point() + geom_line(method='lm') + facet_grid("day",scales='free_x') + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%H:%M"),breaks='1 hour')`

[image]

As you can see, the geom_line() function is showing the points in their correct location. However, geom_point appears to be transforming the data and snapping it to 00:00 hours of each day. Why is this?